# Share file stream between Python and C

Tags: python, c, file

I've been trying to integrate C code into Python under Linux and I came up with the following problem: ¿is it possible to share an already opened file between C and Python? I mean a C FILE and a Python file object.

The C function which I'm struggling with is called exhaustively, so I'd like to avoid opening/closing the file each time this happens and pass the opened file from Python to C. I'm open to any efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible. In C, you can get the file descriptor with `fileno(fh)` and open it in Python with `os.fdopen(fd)`. Make sure you remember to close it -- I doubt that the Python file object going out of scope would accomplish this.